# I cannot use the pointer from QMainWindow as argument in connect for QT5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-connection

This code creates a thread and connect it to `MainWindow` in `QT`.

```
void UI_handling::create_thread_for_looping_terminal(){
    loop_terminal_thread = new Loop_terminal_thread(mainWindow, &j1939);
    loop_terminal_thread->start();
    mainWindow->connect(loop_terminal_thread, &Loop_terminal_thread::send_ID_and_data_to_looping_terminal, mainWindow, &MainWindow::update_looping_teriminal);
}
```

This code gives error on `->connect` part due to `mainWindow` argument.

If I would run this code inside the `MainWindow` class, it would look like this. It will work fine, but as you can see, `mainWindow` is the issue here.

```
connect(loop_terminal_thread, &Loop_terminal_thread::send_ID_and_data_to_looping_terminal, this, &MainWindow::update_looping_teriminal);
```

So why is `mainWindow` the issue if I have a constructor that look like this

```
UI_handling::UI_handling(QMainWindow* mainWindow, Ui::MainWindow* ui) : mainWindow(mainWindow), ui(ui){

}
```

And I call the `UI_handling` constructor inside the `MainWindow` class

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) , ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
    ui->setupUi(this);

    /* Important handler */
    ui_handling = new UI_handling(this, ui);
```

So why does the argument `this`, causing so I don't get right argument?

The error is:

```
ui_handling.cpp:119:17: error: no matching member function for call to 'connect'
qobject.h:242:43: note: candidate function [with Func1 = void (Loop_terminal_thread::*)(unsigned int, unsigned char *), Func2 = void (MainWindow::*)(unsigned int, unsigned char *)] not viable: cannot convert from base class pointer 'QMainWindow *' to derived class pointer 'const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<void (MainWindow::*)(unsigned int, unsigned char *)>::Object *' (aka 'const MainWindow *') for 3rd argument
qobject.h:222:36: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'void (Loop_terminal_thread::*)(uint32_t, uint8_t *)' to 'const char *' for 2nd argument
qobject.h:225:36: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'void (Loop_terminal_thread::*)(uint32_t, uint8_t *)' to 'const QMetaMethod' for 2nd argument
qobject.h:481:41: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'void (Loop_terminal_thread::*)(uint32_t, uint8_t *)' to 'const char *' for 2nd argument
qobject.h:283:13: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '!QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<void (MainWindow::*)(unsigned int, unsigned char *)>::IsPointerToMemberFunction' was not satisfied [with Func1 = void (Loop_terminal_thread::*)(unsigned int, unsigned char *), Func2 = void (MainWindow::*)(unsigned int, unsigned char *)]
qobject.h:322:13: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<void (MainWindow::*)(unsigned int, unsigned char *)>::ArgumentCount == -1' was not satisfied [with Func1 = void (Loop_terminal_thread::*)(unsigned int, unsigned char *), Func2 = void (MainWindow::*)(unsigned int, unsigned char *)]
qobject.h:274:13: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
qobject.h:314:13: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
```

**Minimal example:**

First you create the thread header

```
#ifndef LOOP_TERMINAL_THREAD_H

#define LOOP_TERMINAL_THREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>

class Loop_terminal_thread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Loop_terminal_thread(QObject *parent = nullptr);
signals:
    void send_ID_and_data_to_looping_terminal(uint32_t ID, uint8_t data[]);
private:
    bool* start_loop_terminal_thread;
    void run();
};

#endif // LOOP_TERMINAL_THREAD_H
```

Then you create the thread source

```
#include "loop_terminal_thread.h"

Loop_terminal_thread::Loop_terminal_thread(QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)  {

}

void Loop_terminal_thread::run(){
    uint8_t data[8] = {0};
    data[1] = 23;
    while(1){
            emit send_ID_and_data_to_looping_terminal(300, data);
        msleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Then you create the `UI_handler` class

```
/* QT includes */
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QIntValidator>
#include <QMainWindow>

/* Project includes */
#include "UI_threads/Loop_terminal_thread/loop_terminal_thread.h"

class UI_handling{
public:
    UI_handling(QMainWindow* mainWindow, Ui::MainWindow* ui);
    void create_thread_for_looping_terminal();

private:
    QMainWindow* mainWindow;
    Ui::MainWindow* ui;

    /* Thread for the looping terminal */
    Loop_terminal_thread* loop_terminal_thread;

};

#endif // UI_HANDLING_H
```

And you implement the counstructor and the function inside the source file.

```
UI_handling::UI_handling(QMainWindow* mainWindow, Ui::MainWindow* ui) : mainWindow(mainWindow), ui(ui){

}

void UI_handling::create_thread_for_looping_terminal(){
    loop_terminal_thread = new Loop_terminal_thread(mainWindow, &j1939);
    loop_terminal_thread->start();
    mainWindow->connect(loop_terminal_thread, &Loop_terminal_thread::send_ID_and_data_to_looping_terminal, mainWindow, &MainWindow::update_looping_teriminal);
}
```

Then lastly you implement this inside your `MainWindow` constructor

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) , ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
    ui->setupUi(this);

    /* Important handler */
    ui_handling = new UI_handling(this, ui);
    ui_handling->create_thread_for_looping_terminal();
}

void MainWindow::update_looping_teriminal(uint32_t ID, uint8_t data[]){

}
```

The header file of `MainWindow` class look like this

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void update_looping_teriminal(uint32_t ID, uint8_t data[]);
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: There are unregistered data types, you have tried using container like QVector<uint8_t> or QList<uint8_t> instead of `uint8_t []`.

Comment: @eyllanesc I don't think that's the issue because it still works if I run `connect` inside the `MainWindow` class, but not in `UI_handling` class. I think there is some issues with the pointer `mainWindow`

Comment: mmm, try change `mainWindow->connect` to `QObject::connect`

Comment: @eyllanesc Same error there. Here is the complete code by the way. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/OpenSourceLogger/blob/f890f6f3ca82a899c8d9f547d6432a6cf3d06bb7/Window/Main/UI/ui_handling.cpp#L119

Comment: @eyllanesc Problem solved =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in this part of the error message:

```
cannot convert from base class pointer 'QMainWindow *'
to derived class pointer ... (aka 'const MainWindow *') for 3rd argument
```

You are connecting to a slot in `MainWindow` class, therefore you need to provide a pointer to `MainWindow`. A pointer to `QMainWindow` is not enough.

When you run your connect inside `MainWindow` and pass `this`, then the type of this argument is `MainWindow` and it works.

In order for your code to work you need to change `UI_handling` class, so that it stores a pointer to `MainWindow` instead of `QMainWindow`.

Comment: Yes! This solved it `MainWindow* mainWindow = static_cast<MainWindow*>(qMainWindow);`

Comment: Never been using `static_cast` before in C++.

Comment: `static_cast` seems a weird choice to me. I'd rather change `mainWindow` member in `UI_handling` class from `QMainWindow*` to `MainWindow*` (and modify the `UI_handling` constructor appropriately).

Comment: I could not do that because `this` is the class `QMainWindow` and not `MainWindow`.

Comment: Huh? In `MainWindow` constructor, where you create `UI_handling`, `this` is definitely `MainWindow`.

Comment: It did not work. See my code at my GitHub https://github.com/DanielMartensson/OpenSourceLogger/blob/f890f6f3ca82a899c8d9f547d6432a6cf3d06bb7/Window/Main/UI/ui_handling.cpp#L119

Comment: Example code of the solution would really help